# How to convert a comma separated string from an ACF field to be used in str_ireplace

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a profanity filter in a wordpress site. Everything works fine when I use a normal array
example: str_replace("world","Peter","Hello world!");

However, I'm running into an issue using an associative array. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
  function customforumcontent($content) {
      $censored = get_field('banned_words_list', 'option'); // Gets text field of comma seperated values
      $censored = explode(",", $censored); // Create an associative array  
      $replace = '<b>[censored]</b>'; // Word to replace the banned word(s)

      $content = str_ireplace(array_keys($censored), $replace, $content); // Where my problem seems to be occurring

      return $content;
  }
     add_filter('asgarosforum_filter_post_content', 'customforumcontent');
```

Comment: What makes you think `explode` would create an _associative_ array? It creates a normal numerically indexed one, so after `array_keys($censored)` what you are actually trying to replace here now, will at best be the values `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$content = 'I have a red car and a blue face';
$censored = 'red,blue'; // Gets text field of comma seperated values
$censored = explode(",", $censored); // Create an array
$censored = array_map('trim', $censored); // Remove any leading or trailing whitespace
$replace = 'green'; // Word to replace the banned word(s)
$content = str_ireplace($censored, $replace, $content);
echo $content; // I have a green car and a green face
```

Note the following new line, which removes any trailing or leading whitespace from your array of banned words:

```
$censored = array_map('trim', $censored);
```

Comment: It is a text area field, with no formatting set. When I echo the value it returns: badword1, badword2, badword3. The reason 'option' is set is that it is being pulled from a theme options page

Comment: Try replacing array_keys($censored) with just $censored

Comment: Still nothing. in the documentation, str_irelace is expecting an array like ('word1', word2, 'word3'), so I think the format of the array is throwing it off

Comment: Are you getting anything back at all, or is it returning $content without replacing any censored words?

Comment: Yes it's returning the original content without the censored words being replaced

Comment: I've just tried a sample, which works for me. Will add to my answer

Comment: AH - is there trailing space in your string of bad words, e.g. 'red, blue'. If so you will need to remove the whitespace

Comment: That was it!! Thank you!

Comment: :) NP - I'll add something about whitespace to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `preg_replace` with case insensitive flag:

```
$content = preg_replace("~".implode("|",$cencored)."~i", $replace, $content);
```